# How can I setup pglogic between two AWS Aurora clusters?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am using AWS Aurora postgresql11 and want to use pglogic to setup the replica to another Aurora cluster in the same account/region.

I followed this doc: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical to set up the whole flow but stuck on creating subscription.

What I did is to create two nodes in the source and target clusters by using `pglogical.create_node`.

```
# in source cluster
select pglogical.create_node(node_name := 'master-replica', dsn := 'host=xxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=mydb');

# in target cluster
select pglogical.create_node(node_name := 'slave-replica', dsn := 'host=xxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=mydb');
```

But when I create subscription

```
select pglogical.create_subscription(subscription_name := 'subscription1', provider_dsn := 'host=xxxxx.cluster-clkciynowztg.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=mydb');

ERROR:  could not connect to the postgresql server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I didn't specify any username/password, why it complains about authentication error?

Answer (score 0):

Below AWS article might help.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/postgresql-bi-directional-replication-using-pglogical/

And in *create_node* function, for *dsn* argument, you should provide user=pguser password=xxxx also.

e.g.

`select pglogical.create_node(node_name :='node1', dsn := 'host=<db-endpoint> port=5432 dbname=<dbname> user=pguser password=****);`